# Team Foundation Server 2010 Proxy setup in different domain than Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: proxy

Currently we are connecting from our development machines directly to a Team Foundation Server 2010 which is deployed in a remote datacenter and in a different domain. In order to connect to it, we need to go through a ISA Server which allows traffic for 80 and 8080 ports.

In order to save network bandwith and prevent performance loss due to occasional network problems outside our LAN, we have decided to set up a Team Foundation Server 2010 Proxy in one of our local servers. We have created a local domain account for the TFSPROXY account and give it "log on as a service" privileges. We have used this account in the server using Visual Studio to access the remote TFS files and we have found no problems. In the remote TFS we have created a local account with the same user name and password, and added it to the Team Foundation Proxy Service Accounts TFS and to the Team Foundation Administrators group.

After configuring Visual Studio to use the local Team Foundation Server Proxy we see the following error message in the Output window:

> The source control proxy 'XXXX' is not responding, so the request will be sent to the main server.  Please verify your settings.
>   Additional information:
>     TF15013: The requested Team Foundation Server is not registered with the proxy server.

We have checked all steps detailed in the TFS 2010 installation guide and we think that there is nothing missing. We have ensured that the proxy.config points to the correct URL. Our intention is to point to the tfs virtual folder to cache all files from all collections.

Could be a way to trace what is happening behind the scenes between the proxy and the server in order to know which setting is missing??

Thanks in advance.

Jose Antonio

Comment: Have you looked at the traffic with Fiddler or Wireshark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we found what the problem was, it was a matter of the ISA Server proxy. By default the TFS 2010 proxy does not make use of the default proxy, and you have to tweak the web.config file in the Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Version Control Proxy\Web Services folder.

We have changed it so that now looks like this:

```
  <defaultProxy>
     <proxy usesystemdefault="True" bypassonlocal="True"/>
  </defaultProxy>
```

Hope this helps to others in the same situation.

Jose Antonio